# Where to declare ViewControllers for a custom tab view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabview

I'm trying to figure out how to use a custom tab view I found called `JMTabView` by Jason Morrissey on GitHub. (I tried asking him directly but got no response.)

I know how to programmatically create a `UITabBarController` and assign view controllers. What I can't figure out is where to declare my four `UITableViewController`s and other VC's for each of the four tabs in this example. The code:

```
// TabDemoAppDelegate.m -> do I declare them here?

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
TabDemoViewController * demoViewController = [[[TabDemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:demoViewController] autorelease];
//[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

// TabDemoViewController.m -> or somewhere in here?

-(void)addCustomTabView; { // this is a private method
JMTabView * tabView = [[[JMTabView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 60., self.view.bounds.size.width, 60.)] autorelease];
tabView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[tabView setDelegate:self];

UIImage * standardIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon3.png"];
UIImage * highlightedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];

CustomTabItem * tabItem1 = [CustomTabItem tabItemWithTitle:@"One" icon:standardIcon alternateIcon:highlightedIcon];
CustomTabItem * tabItem2 = [CustomTabItem tabItemWithTitle:@"Two" icon:standardIcon alternateIcon:highlightedIcon];
CustomTabItem * tabItem3 = [CustomTabItem tabItemWithTitle:@"Three" icon:standardIcon alternateIcon:highlightedIcon];
CustomTabItem * tabItem4 = [CustomTabItem tabItemWithTitle:@"Four" icon:standardIcon alternateIcon:highlightedIcon];

[tabView addTabItem:tabItem1];
[tabView addTabItem:tabItem2];
[tabView addTabItem:tabItem3];
[tabView addTabItem:tabItem4];

[tabView setSelectionView:[CustomSelectionView createSelectionView]];
[tabView setItemSpacing:1.];
[tabView setBackgroundLayer:[[[CustomBackgroundLayer alloc] init] autorelease]];

[tabView setSelectedIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:tabView];
}
```

He mentions blocks... if they're relevant, what are they and is this where I would declare the VC's? If so, how?

```
//    You can run blocks by specifiying an executeBlock: paremeter
//    #if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
//    [tabView addTabItemWithTitle:@"One" icon:nil executeBlock:^{NSLog(@"abc");}];
//    #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular library, but if it follows a similar pattern to UITabViewController I would create properties for your tab (if you need to reference them later) in your App Delegate's .h file and then create your instances in the .m.  If you are just placing the tabs and don't need to reference them directly anymore you should be able to define them in the .m (probably in applicationDidFinishLaunching) and then assign them as tabs and let the tab controller take it from there.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'm not sure how to assign the ViewControllers to the tabs in this scenario.